# Debugging JavaScript using Dragonfly Opera

Tags: opera, opera-dragonfly

[image]

I have used [this link](http://my.opera.com/community/forums/topic.dml?id=984572) and installed Opera Dragonfly locally as mentioned. But now I am unable to load the JavaScript for debugging. Attached the screenshot of error. Any idea on resolving this?

I am using Opera 12.

My dragonfly environment is : 
Protocol Version: 1
Core Version: 2.10.289
Operating System: Win32
Platform: Win32
User Agent: Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 5.1; U; en) Presto/2.10.289 Version/12.00
Opera Dragonfly Version: $dfversion$
Revision Number: $revdate$

Comment: rather you could use Firefox - FireBug plugin which helps you do so. - Very useful and effective for web developers and JS programmers

Comment: have you downloaded 1.5 year old zip and expect it to run on modern opera ? Running local Dragonfly copy (aka "offline") is a bit of a hassle, (and was never was worth all the troubles, at least for me). But if you still think you need it - check this reference (and keep in mind that you need to download from gitHub now, not from bitBucket) - http://my.opera.com/dragonfly/blog/running-opera-dragonfly-offline

Comment: But you can simply click `Ctrl+Shift+I` and run normal Dragonfly, which works like a charm (unless you are behind proxy, but for that, you'll need some extra tricks).

Comment: yep.. i am under proxy. so I am using it locally. Thanks :)\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I never tried out Dragonfly locally.

I see one potential problem with the post containing the link to the dragonfly zip-file.
This line here: `5. May 2011, 10:52:51`
Are you sure that your version of Opera is still compatible to this version of Dragonfly?

[This Repository](https://github.com/operasoftware/dragonfly) contains the freshest version of Dragonfly available. Check out the integrated hints on how to build dragonfly. (I think building isn't even necessary if you are okay with some performance losses)

#### The following helps on general questions:

Did you select the right debugging context?

Either start Dragonfly from the Window you want to debug by pressing `Ctrl+Shift+I` or select the right context using the rightmost button below your zoom-slider in your screenshot.